# How to align text to the right in ttk Treeview widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am using a `ttk.Treeview` widget to display a *list of Arabic books*. Arabic is a right-to-left language, so the text should be aligned to the right. 
The justify option that is available for `Label` and other `ttk` widgets does not seem to work for `Treeview`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `ttk.Treeview` widget has an [`anchor`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html#ttk.Treeview.column) option you can set for each column. To set the anchor of a column to the right side use:

```
ttk.Treeview.column(column_id, anchor=Tkinter.E)
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the @fhdrsdg answer, here you have a simple example of use:

```
# for python 3
import tkinter as tk  
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


def show_info():
    messagebox.showinfo("More info", "First column represents the subject" \
                        " and the second represents its corresponding " \
                        "current number of tagged questions on Stack Overflow.")

root = tk.Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=("Tags"), height=6)

subjects = {"Tkinter": "8,013",
            "Python": "425,865",
            "C++": "369,851",
            "Java": "858,459"}

for subject in subjects.keys():
    tree.insert("", "end", text=subject, values=(subjects[subject]))

tree.column("Tags", anchor="e")    
tree.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

informer = tk.Button(root, text="More info", command=show_info)
informer.pack(side="bottom")


root.mainloop()
```

If you need more help on how to use `ttk.Treeview` widgets, have a look at [this reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20190530090350/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html) by The New Mexico Tech or [this tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html) at TkDocs.