# how to "center text in a row" tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I want to center text in rows. I used tkinter for GUI. Which code should I use and where?

```
tv1["column"]=list(pivot.columns)
tv1["show"] = "headings"
for column in tv1["columns"]:
    tv1.heading(column, text = column)
    
pivot_rows = pivot.to_numpy().tolist()
for row in pivot_rows:
    tv1.insert("","end", values=row)
```

[image: GUI]

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30393763/13382000)

Comment: i tried this one, it changed column. I want to change the rows position.

Comment: Try `tv1.column("#1", anchor="center")` to change the second row, or whatever`cid` you have for the second column. ([source](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Treeview.html))

Answer (score 1):

```py
tv1["column"] = list(pivot.columns)
tv1["show"] = "headings"
for column in tv1["columns"]:
    tv1.column(column, anchor=CENTER) # This will center text in rows
    tv1.heading(column, text=column)
    
pivot_rows = pivot.to_numpy().tolist()
for row in pivot_rows:
    tv1.insert("","end", values=row)
```

Found in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#id7)